# Managing shared dll correctly in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll

I'm developing a dll that is to be used in two Unity projects.

I've read that the way to reference a dll is to drag it into a 'plugins' folder so that it is added to the Unity project's dependencies, as their is no "add reference" available for this project in Visual Studio.

But doing that the Unity project does not take into account that the dll evolves (as it is still in development).

What I'd like (if possible) is to set up an automatic way so that the Unity projects update their dependencies when the shared dll is updated.

I've try the reimport option (right click on the dll in Unity) but it seems that it is not working.

What is the best way to manage this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of things we did for this was to setup a post build script in our Visual Studio solution that would generate the .dll and copy it to the desired plugins folder in our Unity project. Whenever the dll is changed, Unity will reimport it. So if you're not seeing unity recognize any changes, it means that the dll it has locally is not what is being rebuilt by visual studio. At the very least, if your visual studio project is set up as a class library, then when you rebuild it should place the dll in a /bin/debug/ folder that you could manually copy over.

Comment: To clarify, we kept our dll source adjacent to the Unity Assets folder so we could reliably use relative paths in the post build script and keep both projects (Unity and source) under the same version control project.